# TabLayout сделать таб активным

Tags: android, android-viewpager, tabs

У меня есть `TabLayout` с `id=tabLayout`. В нем есть две вкладки, которые листают страницы во `ViewPager`'e. Страницы добавлены программно, с помощью фрагментов. Как мне сделать, чтобы при открытии определенной страницы, у активного таба появлялась полоска внизу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в вашей разметке в тэг `TabLayout`

```
app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp"
```

И цвет до кучи

```
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
```